# How can send every 500 employeed id to Oracle to resolve ORA-07195

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I already have this code to make stringBuilder for every employee,  I  get all the employeesId from another table  . But if I get more than 1000 employees, I get the error ORA-07195 , I know this error is related to a Maximum of expression in a list . Therefore how can I send every 500 employees to my query in Data Access Objects.

```
Public List<GraphModel> countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(int year, int month, String employeeID)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int countEmployeess = 0;
        string employeesid = "";

        DataView dv = _employeeOverrideBO.getRelatedEmployees(year, month, employeeID);
        StringBuilder listEmployees = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < countEmployees; i += 500) 
        {

        foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
        {
            DataRow row = rowView.Row;
            String employee = row["EMPLOYEE_ID"].ToString();
            if (count > 0)
                listEmployees.Append(",");
            listEmployees.Append("'").Append(employee).Append("'"); 
            count++;
        }

        }
        countEmployeess++;
        employeesid = listEmployees.ToString();

        return _requestDAO.countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(employeesid);
```

Also this is my query in Data Access Object

```
public List<GraphModel> countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(string employeesIds)
    {
        String sql = " select NVL(TO_CHAR(RR.REASON_NM_NEW), 'Total') as SERIES1, count(*) AS VAL" +
                     " from REQUEST R, REQUEST_PERSON RP, REQUEST_REASON RR " +
                     " WHERE R.STATUS IN ('CREATED', 'PENDING APPROVAL', 'APPROVED BY MANAGER', 'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS') " +
                     " AND R.REQUEST_ID = RP.REQUEST_ID" +
                     " AND RP.REQUEST_ROLE = 'REQUESTOR' " +
                     " AND RR.REASON_ID = R.REASON_ID" +
                     " AND RP.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (" + employeesIds + ") " +
                     " group by rollup (RR.REASON_NM_NEW) " + 
                     " ORDER BY count(*)  DESC";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql);


        try
        {
            DataTable dataTable = Data_base_Access.executeSQL(cmd, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stage"].ToString());
            return (GraphModel.convertToList(dataTable));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.writeError("Request DAO", ex);
            throw new DataAccessException("There was an error counting the open requests");
        }
    }
```

Also this query get the count to list called GraphModel

```
     public static List<GraphModel> convertToList(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
    {
        List<GraphModel> list = new List<GraphModel>();
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(convertToGraphModel(dtRow));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static GraphModel convertToGraphModel(DataRow dtRow)
    {

        GraphModel graphModel = new GraphModel();

        if (dtRow.Table.Columns.Contains("SERIES1") && dtRow["SERIES1"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            graphModel.SERIES1 = Convert.ToString(dtRow["SERIES1"]);
        }

        if (dtRow.Table.Columns.Contains("SERIES2") && dtRow["SERIES2"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            graphModel.SERIES2 = Convert.ToString(dtRow["SERIES2"]);
        }

        if (dtRow.Table.Columns.Contains("VAL") && dtRow["VAL"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            graphModel.VAL = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["VAL"]);
        }


        return graphModel;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your help because I am research a lot and I dont know what can I do

Answer (score 0):

Split the list into 1000 item lists and change the query into this:

```
" AND (RP.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (" + ids_1_1000 + ") OR RP.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (" + ids_1001_2000 + "))" +
```

Comment: I think the problem is the string is to big or is the `IN()` ?

Comment: @SamuelNeff - The limit is 1000 elements not 500.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for correction, I updated the answer to reflect 1000 per group. The OP mentioned getting the error at 1000 and for some reason asked about grouping them by 500.

Answer (score 0):

One of the features I love most about Oracle is the Oracle Call Interface (OCI) that lets you access some of the more powerful features or Oracle with programming languages.  In particular, for this example, the ability to do bulk inserts should prove very helpful.

If, instead of the approach you have above, which is trying to insert thousands of literals into a single SQL statement, you put those values into a table and do a join, I think you will:

1. Spare the shared pool from having to compile a really nasty SQL statement
2. Eliminate the need to escape strings or worry about SQL Injection
3. Have a lightning fast query that substitutes a join (bread and butter for a database) for a giant in-list

Step 1: Create a GTT:

```
create global temporary table employee_list (
  employee_id varchar2(100) not null
) on commit preserve rows;
```

The GTT is based on a session, so even if you have this code running in multiple instances, each GTT will act as a blank slate for each instance -- no possibility of collisions of data.

Step 2: Within your code, create a `transaction` to handle the fact that you need the insert to the table and the select on the data to occur as part of the same transaction:

```
OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

Step 3: Use ODP.net's bulk insert capabilities to insert all of your employee Ids at once.  I encourage you to benchmark this versus inserting them one at a time.  You'll be amazed.  If you have more than 50,000, then *maybe* you need to break the up into chunks, but with a single field, I think this should be more than adequate:

```
// string[] employeesIds

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into employee_list values (:EMPLOYEE)",
    conn);
cmd.Transaction = trans;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMPLOYEE", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = employeesIds;
cmd.ArrayBindCount = employeesIds.Length;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note `employeeIds` should be an array.

Step 4: Change your SQL from an in-list to a join:

```
 select NVL(TO_CHAR(RR.REASON_NM_NEW), 'Total') as SERIES1, count(*) AS VAL
 from
   REQUEST R,
   REQUEST_PERSON RP,
   REQUEST_REASON RR,
   employee_list e       -- added this
 WHERE R.STATUS IN ('CREATED', 'PENDING APPROVAL', 'APPROVED BY MANAGER',
     'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS')
 AND R.REQUEST_ID = RP.REQUEST_ID
 AND RP.REQUEST_ROLE = 'REQUESTOR'
 AND RR.REASON_ID = R.REASON_ID
 AND RP.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.employee_id  -- changed this
 group by rollup (RR.REASON_NM_NEW)
 ORDER BY count(*)  DESC
```

And here's what it would all look like together:

```
public List<GraphModel> countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(string[] employeesIds)
{
    OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into employee_list values (:EMPLOYEE)",
        conn);
    cmd.Transaction = trans;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMPLOYEE", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = employeesIds;
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = employeesIds.Length;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    String sql = "";  // code from above goes here

    cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Transaction = trans;

    DataTable dataTable = null;

    try
    {
        dataTable = Data_base_Access.executeSQL(cmd,
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stage"].ToString());
        return (GraphModel.convertToList(dataTable));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.writeError("Request DAO", ex);
        throw new DataAccessException("There was an error counting the open requests");
    }
    finally
    {
        trans.Rollback();
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this code..

```
public List<GraphModel> countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(int year, int month, String employeeID)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int countEmployees = 0;
        Dictionary<string, int> dataChart = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        DataView dv = _employeeOverrideBO.getRelatedEmployeesRequests(year, month, employeeID);
        StringBuilder listEmployees = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv) 
        {
            if (countEmployees == 500)
            {
                List<GraphModel> listReturn = _requestDAO.countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(listEmployees.ToString());

                foreach(GraphModel model in listReturn){

                    if (dataChart.ContainsKey(model.SERIES1))
                    {
                        dataChart[model.SERIES1] = dataChart[model.SERIES1] + model.VAL;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataChart[model.SERIES1] = model.VAL;
                    }

                }
                listEmployees = new StringBuilder();
                count = 0;
                countEmployees = 0;
            }

            DataRow row = rowView.Row;
            String employee = row["EMPLOYEE_ID"].ToString();
            if (count > 0)
                listEmployees.Append(",");
            listEmployees.Append("'").Append(employee).Append("'");
            count++;

            countEmployees++;

        }

        //Last Call
        List<GraphModel> listReturnLast = _requestDAO.countRequestCreatedByTypeDefaulPage(listEmployees.ToString());
        foreach (GraphModel model in listReturnLast) {

            if (dataChart.ContainsKey(model.SERIES1))
            {
                dataChart[model.SERIES1] = dataChart[model.SERIES1] + model.VAL;
            }
            else
            {
                dataChart[model.SERIES1] = model.VAL;
            }

        }




        List<GraphModel> list = new List<GraphModel>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in dataChart)
        {
            GraphModel model = new GraphModel();
            model.SERIES1 = entry.Key;
            model.VAL = entry.Value;
            list.Add(model);
        }

        return list;
    }
```